# Persistent iptables with Docker: rules get restored multiple times when using if-pre-up.d

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, docker

**Additional Context (may be skipped)**

I'm trying to set up psad on my system, which requires to add a rule to the iptables `iptables -A INPUT -j LOG`. Of course, this rule will get flushed upon reboot, so i looked into ways of making it persistent (of which there are many).

While the `iptables-persistent` package seems to be the most convenient solution, I cannot use it, as it clashes with the docker daemon running on the system, as `iptables-persistent` just runs `iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4` without the `-n` flag, which may destroy any changes to iptables from the docker-daemon.

**Actual Question**

So I didn't want to disable the automatic iptable rules from the docker daemon entirely, as it just creates a huge maintenance hassle, so I just added a script

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables-restore -n < /etc/network/iptables.rules
```

to `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d` with `chmod +x` and saved the configuration *without* the docker rules with `iptables-save > /etc/network/iptables.rules`.

The file `iptables.rules` then just says

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j LOG
```

But when I reboot the system, i see the rule `-A INPUT -j LOG` three times. My current guess is that this may be because `/etc/network/firewall` gets executed multiple times (because there are multiple interfaces??).

How do I resolve this issue? Note that `rc.local` is deprecated and not meant for this purpose as it is not run when the iptables service is restarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I just created a systemd service that runs the script once and removed it from `if-pre-up.d`